# Html().replace() : RegExp : $1 and single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, quote

I am faced with two problems. (with jQuery)

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var e = arr[i],               //<- strings
        re = new RegExp(e,"ig");
    target.html(
        target.html().replace(
            re, "<span class='rep'>" + e + "</span>"
        )
    );
}
```

1. The original value cannot be called after replacing. (like a "$1")
2. It cannot replace, if the candidate for substitution (property e) has a single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can use something similar to `$1`:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var e = arr[i],               //<- strings
        re = new RegExp(e,"ig");
    target.html(
        target.html().replace(
            re, "<span class='rep'>$&</span>"
        )
    ); //you could also have used $1 to refer to the first backreference, instead of the entire match
}
```

Your second problem is less clear to me. Single quotes are not special characters in regexes.

I could not replicate your other problem. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xsjt7/1/

Comment: wow, thank you for the advice.  "$&" worked!! It was long outstanding problem at me.  About second problem, for example, "don't" or "won't" and some words is not replaced.  It seems that the character is normally set up if it sees by a console log.

Comment: That depends on what you are using as your regex, ie what is in your array of strings.

Comment: I'm sorry when I don't understand your advice.  
this is result of console.log() : 
`RegExp /what/ig`  `RegExp /not make any sense/ig`  `RegExp /n't make any sense/ig`  `RegExp /it's/ig`
  
At this time, "n't make any sense" and "it's" is not replaced.
Is the recognition point in question different?

Comment: @JIGEN I can't reproduce your problem. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xsjt7/1/

Comment: Thank you for the polite sample.  
I found the cause.  
It was another issue.  
I have drawn the text by the template engine (Twig) of PHP.   
There, it was displayed as "it’s" instead of "it's".  
Thank you for the advice.  
Now, I consider drawing of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `$1` and the arr is just an array of strings you could join it:

```
var arr = ["what","not make any sense","n't make any sense","it's"];
var target = $('#mydiv');

var re = new RegExp("(" + arr.join("|") +")","ig");
target.html(
    target.html().replace(re, "<span class='rep'>$1</span>")
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I think that I will use "$&".